# Can .txt file be retrieved to textview from parse.com

Tags: android

Can I add .txt file in parse.com and retrieve it to my textview in my app. I know how to add a string and retrieve it but have a confusion regarding the .Txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your creating your `ParseFile` object, you can give it a file type by adding the file extension to the end of the key name.

Eg:

`ParseFile file = new ParseFile("sometext.txt", fileData);`

will create a text file the the contents of `fileData`. This can be attached to a `ParseObject` and saved/retrieved from Parse the usual way.

By the way, you should give this question a parse.com tag.

Comment: Sent for not adding the tag and thanks for the answer

Comment: I meant sorry not sent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33564504/5524159.   .this is my original question .please have a look and please answer

Comment: Sorry didn't see it happen

Comment: Thanks for asking without hesitation

Comment: @Orbit If the .txt file was already on parse.com, how can i download that .txt file, convert it to string and display in a textview?

Comment: @LizG This would be better asked as its own question, but the Parse docs go over retrieving objects fairly well: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects

Comment: @Orbit I have a question on here but getting no responses ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980706/receive-txt-file-from-parse-com-and-place-in-textview - i have no problem retrieving, its converting it to string and then storing that string into textview - not in parse docs