# Receive text file from parse.com and place in textview

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, textview

I am trying to get the text from a text file in Parse and convert it to    String and place the text in a textview.  I tried doing what someone   suggested while researching by doing it the same way as an image (AppetizerRecipe.java)

As you can see from the images, i have a column "recipe" that consists of text files.  The logcat shows that the file is retrieved from parse and when I click on it, it shows me my file.  I can't seem to get the text onto my textview.

onListItemClick:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long
        id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ParseObject po = mAppetizers.get(position);

    ParseFile recipes = po.getParseFile("recipe");


    // TODO: Get fields from Parse
    String title = po.getString(AppetizerRecipe.ARG_NAME);
    String time = po.getString(AppetizerRecipe.ARG_TIME);
    String ID = po.getObjectId().toString();
        Log.d("Appetizer", "object: " + ID);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Appetizer.this, AppetizerRecipe.class);

    // TODO: Put extras
    intent.putExtra(AppetizerRecipe.ARG_NAME, title);
    intent.putExtra(AppetizerRecipe.ARG_TIME, time);
    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
        Log.d("Appetizer", "object: " + ID);


    startActivity(intent); // TODO:  In other activity, get these extras
}
```

AppetizerRecipe.java

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> gettext = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers"); 
    gettext.addAscendingOrder("appetizer"); 
    gettext.whereEqualTo("ID", ID); 
    gettext.getInBackground(ID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject textobject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                final ParseFile textObject = (ParseFile) textobject.get("recipe");
                textObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // use data for something

                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "Error Message..." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

parse.com:

[image: parse.com]

Logcat:

[image: Logcat]

Text file from parse.com:

[image: Text file from parse.com]

Comment: Anyone have any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: Where are you trying to load your `String` into your `TextView`? You need to upload all relevant code.

Comment: In AppetizerRecipe.java after the 2nd if (e == null) ... I have tried so many things that when i uploaded this image, i took out what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `String` from a `byte[]`:

```
//your byte[] being data
String str = new String(data);
```

and then set the `String` on your `TexView` like:

```
textView.setText(str);
```